# catching like/dislike in my canvas application

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I added a `like` button to the canvas application page that actually configured to the facebook page of the application.

I would like that whenever a user pressed like or dislike on my page, a request will be sent to my server noticing it that the user liked or disliked the application page.

I can catch these events by using the following code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);

});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
    alert('You disliked the URL: ' + response);
});
```

I can just check if the response equals to my facebook application page. 
the question is.. after I catched the like or dislike, how do i forward it to the server secure enough ? how can I send the request to the server without posting the facebook id as a post/get parameter?

i want to send it to the server in a way that the server will be able to fetch the facebook session information and fetch the userid from there, or any other secure way.

example:

if i'll just call http://mysite/liked_my_app?uid=4534534543

then a user notice this request and start sending liked_my_app with fake uids.

is there a way to prevent that somehow ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the UID of the user, forward the `signed_request`.  Only **you** can decode signed requests coming from your application because of the `app_secret` you have to use to decode it.

Another possible solution (depending on what exactly you want to do when you confirm a like/dislike event) is to check at intervals your page/app like count - in a cron job for example.  When a user likes your page/app you can retrieve his UID (possibly other information as well), and you can cross-reference the lists from the last cron job.